# Send mail using XOAuth2 + Spring Boot + JavaMail + office365 SMTP

Tags: spring-boot, azure, email, oauth-2.0, smtp

**Summary**

I'm trying to send an email from a JAVA application via SMTP smtp.office365.com by authenticating myself to the server with the XOAuth2 protocol

**Configuration information on Azure AD:**

```
1. On the registration of a new application
1.1 In the Authentication part
1.1.1. Adding a platform "Desktop and mobile application" and selecting MSAL for the redirection uri
1.1.2. Activation of the "no keyboard" flow
1.2 In the Certificates & Secrets section
1.2.1. Generation of a client secret (valid)
2. On the managed application
2.1. In the users part
2.1.1 Adding the user who owns the sender address (messagerie@domain.com)
```

**application.properties**

```
# Spring
spring.mail.host=smtp.office365.com
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=messagerie@domain.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.sasl.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.sasl.mechanisms=XOAUTH2
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth.xoauth2.authority=https://login.microsoftonline.com/e***a/
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth.xoauth2.client.id=b***c
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth.xoauth2.client.secret=4***A
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth.xoauth2.scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.test-connection=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=true
```

**MailHelper.java**

```java
@Component
public class MailHelper {
    private String clientId;
    private String clientSecret;
    private String scope;
    private String authority;
    private String username;
    private JavaMailSender emailSender;

    private IAuthenticationResult getToken() throws MalformedURLException {
        final IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(
                this.clientId, 
                ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(this.clientSecret))
            .authority(this.authority)
            .build();
        final ClientCredentialParameters parameters = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(
                Collections.singleton(this.scope))
            .build();
        return app
            .acquireToken(parameters)
            .join();
    }

    public void send(final MimeMessage message) throws MessagingException {
        if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(this.clientId, this.clientSecret, this.scope, this.authority)) {
            try {
                final StringBuilder passwordBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                passwordBuilder.append("user=").append(this.username)
                        .append('\u0001')
                        .append("auth=").append("Bearer ").append(getToken().accessToken())
                        .append('\u0001').append('\u0001');

                final String base64Password = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(passwordBuilder.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                ((JavaMailSenderImpl) this.emailSender).setPassword(base64Password);
            } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new MessagingException("Impossible d'initialiser la connexion OAuth2", e);
            }
        }
        this.emailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

**Bulk information**

- The messagerie@domain.com account can send mails with this SMTP and a login/password connection
- The accessToken retrieval via MSAL4J works fine
- Following the info on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#sasl-xoauth2, I tried to pass in the line `((JavaMailSenderImpl) this.emailSender).setPassword(base64Password);` the accessToken directly before doing the concatenation with the user + accessToken
- I tried to use Microsoft GraphAPI, but in addition to the OAuth information it still asks me for the password. It seems strange to me and I didn't explore this way further (If this is the way to go, I'd like to know why it needs a password in addition to the secret).

All my attempts result in 2 error messages:

- Either a message from JavaMail: `535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [LO4P265CA0135.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]`
- Or an SMTP
  message: `DEBUG SMTP: SASL authentication failed` encapsulated in the
  message `org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect`

Comment: have you tried to use powershell commands https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/fix-issues-with-printers-scanners-and-lob-applications-that-send-email-using-off#error-authentication-unsuccessful just to test if the account is really working.

Comment: Thank you for this lead, it took me a little while to understand it because I don't know Azure well. I finally managed to connect using mail + password, but I don't see how to connect with mail + secret client.
I have the impression that whatever you try with Azure you need to have a user account (mail + password) before being able to use OAuth2.0 secrets. Is this the case?

Comment: never used "secrets" for mail servers, even it is supported you can test with powershell and make sure if it is working or not before jumping into code.